# Horizontal scroll for angular ng-table

Tags: css

Unfortunately my section is quite small in both code and text, but perhaps I'm under the illusion that is all I needed. The context is that I'm trying to introduce a horizontal scroll for my table as the way my table is, I can generate up to an extra 15 columns. My code consist of the following:

```
<div class="ng-table">
    <div style="overflow-x:scroll;">
        <table ng-table="resultsTable"
               class="table table-bordered table-striped margin-bottom-10 pointer"
               show-filter="showFilter">
            <tr ng-repeat="entity in $data">
                 ...
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I searched online and found that the `style="overflow-x:scroll`, and while yes it has added a scroll template on the bottom it doesn't seem to work at all. Any reason what I'm forgetting? Thank you.

Comment: You have to set a `width` to the container for the scroll to work.

Comment: @PPM1988 Sorry how? I deleted the old ones since thought you meant each column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the size of the content inside a block level container exceeds the overall size of the container then naturally a horizontal scroll should be displayed.

As you want the `ng-table` to be scrollable horizontally within the `div` element, set a width for the `div` containing the `ng-table` and also the `overflow-x:scroll` on the div.

```html
    <div style="width:100px;overflow-x:scroll;">
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td>Col 1</td>
       <td>Col 2</td>
       <td>Col 3</td>
       <td>Col 4</td>
       <td>Col 5</td>
       <td>Col 6</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
```